# Randomly fade in and out x elements on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array list of 100 objects that I want to randomly append on to the screen.

```
                for (var i = 0; i < theobject.length; i++) {
                    var item = theobject[Math.floor(Math.random()*theobject.length)];
                    $('.container').append('<div class="theitem"> item.themessage </div>')
                }
```

Ok so my goal is to append five of them at a time on the screen and then randomly replace one by one of those 5 by the next on the "qued list". The one that fades out will be removed from the DOM, also from the object list so it wont get placed again. Any suggestions? Thanks a ton!

Comment: This is a very broad "request" you're making.  Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Looking for guidelines, psuedo code.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

- Instead of taking a random value from the array, first shuffle the array based on random selections. Then you can just iterate that array without having to worry you'll get duplicates
- Use the jQuery `animate` method to clear and set the opacity of one of the 5 elements
- Use the `promise` method to create a promise, and chain a `then` callback which executes when the animation is ready
- Use `delay` to introduce some time before the next item is selected and faded.
- Put this in a self invoking function to make this repeat indefinitely
- Use the `%` operator to implement round robin array traversal

Code:

```js
// Utility function
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

// Some sample data
var theobject = ["Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetur","adipiscing","elit","sed","do","eiusmod","tempor","incididunt","ut","labore","et","dolore","magna","aliqua","Ut","enim","ad","minim","veniam","quis","nostrud","exercitation","ullamco","laboris","nisi","aliquip","ex","ea","commodo","consequat","Duis","aute","irure","in","reprehenderit","voluptate","velit","esse","cillum","eu","fugiat","nulla","pariatur","Excepteur","sint","occaecat","cupidatat","non","proident","sunt","culpa","qui","officia","deserunt","mollit","anim","id","est","laborum"]
    .map(s => ({ themessage: s}));

// 1. Shuffle the array
shuffle(theobject);

// 2. Add the first 5 elements on the page
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('<div>').addClass("theitem").text(theobject[i].themessage).appendTo($('.container'));
}

// 3. Asynchronous loop to select one of those 5 and replace with next from shuffled array
(function loop(i) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    $('.container>.theitem').eq(j).animate({ opacity: 0 }).promise().then(function () {
        return $(this).text(theobject[i].themessage).animate({ opacity: 1 }).delay(500).promise();
    }).then(function () {
        loop((i + 1) % theobject.length);
    });
})(5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Your shuffle algorithm is that so called `Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm`: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Comment: Dude, you rock! Thanks a ton. This will get me started for sure.